# Runtime decorator / annotation with TypeScript 1.5

Tags: typescript

I was wondering if it was possible to have runtime annotation/decorator with typescript 1.5 ? (in a NodeJS / IoJS context)

Meaning that the annotations or decorator is created and interpreted at runtime, and not when we call the specific function ?

Thanks for advance

EDIT :

I need to fill an array of routes at runtime to give them to Restify/Express/Connect using an annotation like this one :

```
@MyRoute({url: "/search/:myCriteria", verb: "GET"})
    getASearchResult() {
        console.log('we got a search result')
    }
```

The problem is that the decorator is interprated only when the method is called.

The fact is that the different routing frameworks need to know the route to be able to redirect to it, before calling the callback associated.

That's why I need to fill an array of routes at runtime, to load my routing framework with the url pattern / verb / callback that it needs to work.

Is this clear ? Else, tell me, I ll edit again :-)

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that the decorator is interprated only when the method is called.
>   The fact is that the different routing frameworks need to know the route to be able to redirect to it, before calling the callback associated.

Static members are executed at the point of definition, so I would do:

```
declare var MyRoute: any;

class Awesome{
    @MyRoute({ url: "/search/:myCriteria", verb: "GET" })
    static getASearchResult() {
        console.log('we got a search result')
    }
}
```

In this case `MyRoute` will be invoked. If you want it on a member function then I would invoke the decorator manually.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will study if using static function is a problem in my case. I think calling the decorator at runtime is not a good idea for me, if I have dozen of routes, it could be weird. I ll study that, thanks for your help

Comment: Another quick question that doesn't need to open another topic. When does the decorator of a class is called ? At instanciation ? What about the property of a class ?

Comment: @Skahrz no, they're both called when the class is declared

Comment: @Skahrz when the code for defining the class is run. To check when it runs, you can debug the code by putting a breakpoint in the decorator (or output to the console within the decorator). I would recommend you take a look at the javascript output to get a better idea about what's going on behind the scenes

Answer (score 0):

> Meaning that the annotations or decorator is created and interpreted at runtime, and not when we call the specific function

That is fairly vague. But for what its worth you can create `function` from a string :

```
var foo = new Function('functionToDecorate','console.log("Function is : " + functionToDecorate.toString()); return functionToDecorate'); 
// usage
function bar(){};
bar = foo(bar);
```

Feel free to use `multiline` strings to make it easier to create functions : http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/template-strings.html

Answer (score 0):

I would use the same approach I referred in:

[Class initialize using typescript decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34782430/class-initialize-using-typescript-decorators/34787085#34787085)

That is to add dummy function in the same module. Then in init phase of your application call it. This will trigger all decorators and you will be able to fill your array or routes before calling the annotated functions.

Hope this will help.