# Class initialize using typescript decorators

Tags: typescript

I want to automatically initialize the class when a specific decorator is present above the class, for example:

```
@apiController
export class usersControllers extends lib.baseClasses.apiControllerBase().apiController {
    @lib.decorators.routesRegister().register({ "url": "/login","isLoginUrl":true})
    public postLoginUser($data) {
        let userDetails = {
            name: 'pranay dutta',
            userType: '1', // must
            age: '26',
            tokenExpiry:5000000 // must
        };

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.ok(userDetails);
        }, 100);

        return this.promise;
    }
}
```

In the above example when i use the `@apiController` decorator it should automatially initilziae the class for me, please help me with the issue

Comment: What have you tried? If you look for documentation, then https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2249 is a good source of information.

Comment: What you mean by saying: "initialize the class"? Is it initializing its static fields?

Comment: it should do something like "new usersControllers()"

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like

```
function apiController(target: any) 
{
    let obj = new target.constructor();
}
```

UPDATE.
To force decorators to fire I use the following trick. Add dummy function in the same module like this:

```
export function Seed() { }
```

and then just call it in the initialize routines or your system. That will force all decorators from that module to fire.

Comment: this function ,won't get invoked until i initialize the class once

Comment: Not exactly. Its enough to force loading of the corresponding module. To do this I usually add dummy functionin the same module like this:

export function Seed() { }

and then just call it in the initialize routines or your system. That will force all decorators to fire

Comment: can you please edit the answer with the dummy function